# Get IPv4 addresses of TOR exit nodes behind Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, cloudflare, tor, real-ip

Please how to tell the visitor comes from onion network if my server operates under Cloudflare?
E.g. with `ngx_http_realip_module` CF returns `$_SERVER[HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP]` with visitor's real IP. But I'm not sure how to manage it in case of IPv6 addresses like 2405:8100:8000:5ca1::e0:d91f.

Without CF I clicked the site using Tor Browser and changed tor circuit many times but have never seen ipv6 from Tor in access log

Are there really existing IPv6 exit list?
Is there another method to detect visitors from Tor Browses if I use Cloudflare?

Answer (score 0):

It seems there are plenty of IPv6 enabled tor exit nodes.

https://metrics.torproject.org/relays-ipv6.html

Answer (score 0):

One guy from CF community gave an idea to use ip geolocation as country code for tor is always T1.
Since CF returns HTTP_CF_CONNECTING_IP it returns also HTTP_CF_IPCOUNTRY that contains T1 in case of TOR exit address